# Adorner resizing: Canvas.GetLeft() returns Nan

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to use the resize adorner i found on this site:
https://denisvuyka.wordpress.com/2007/10/15/wpf-simple-adorner-usage-with-drag-and-resize-operations/

I adjusted my xaml like this

```
<Grid Background="Transparent"
      x:Name="border">
    <Viewbox Stretch="Fill"
             StretchDirection="Both">
        <ContentControl>
            <sourceView:CommentView x:Name="_sourceElementView" />
        </ContentControl>
    </Viewbox>
    <TextBox Width="Auto"
             Height="Auto"
             Margin="15,10,15,40"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
             VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
             AcceptsReturn="True"
             Background="#33FFFFFF"
             BorderThickness="0"
             FontSize="12"
             Text="{Binding Path=PetriElement.Comment,
                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                            Mode=TwoWay}"
             TextWrapping="Wrap" />
</Grid>
```

My codebheind look as suggested by the tutorial. The `Grid` is the interface the adorner. (Replace `myCanvas` with `border` in the tutorial).

The top right thumb and bottom right thumb work fine, but the top left and bottom left thumbs will adjust the width and height but not the position of the control. (The top left corner is fixed)

A problem might be that this line of code in the adorner file always returns `Nan`:

```
double left_old = Canvas.GetLeft(adornedElement);
```

But I dont know how to get the position otherwise and I also dont know if thats the only problem.

Thanks for your help

Comment: If you want to use Canvas methods to work you need... a Canvas! But you have a Grid here.

Comment: @icebat If I use a Canvas instead of a Grid I cannot even resize my control and if I put a Canvas around my Grid its the same behavior as before.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Canvas.GetLeft(adornedElement)` returns the default value `NaN`, unless you have previously set the `Canvas.Left` property on the element, either in XAML or in code-behind. As pointed out by icebat, `adornedElement` must actually be a child element of a Canvas to make the `Canvas.Left` property work. Otherwise it's just ignored. As a general hint, you should not ask people to look into external blogs or tutorials to reproduce your problem. Instead, you should create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).